# Why doesn't my data table render in richfaces 4.0?

Tags: jsf, calendar, richfaces

I tried all the methods that I know but nothing seemed to work on this I even tried re-render and everything but none of them worked.

here is my code:

```
<rich:calendar  id="calendar5" dataModel="#{calendarModel}"
                popup="false" datePattern="yyyy/MM/dd" value="#{calendarModel.selectedDate}"
                boundaryDatesMode="select"
                showApplyButton="false" cellWidth="24px" cellHeight="22px" style="width:200px">

                <a4j:ajax event="change" render="calendar5,dw,table" execute="@this" action="#{weekViewBean.weekList}" listener="#{calendarModel.changeDateListener}"/>

         </rich:calendar>
```

Comment: What *should* happen? You only show code for an `calendar`. I'm guessing you want a component with the id `table` to update in response to your user choosing a date? If so, have you tried the `dateselected` event?

Comment: Try `<a4j:ajax event="change" render="calendar5,dw,table" />` (+ you can switch to newest version of RichFaces: 4.3.5)

Comment: ive already tried it.i "think" i tried all of them but it seems that the problem is rendering the value inside the data table because it renders values of dates for weekView basis